# FLUTTER: Failed assertion: child == null || indexOf(child) > index: is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

When i run the following code and want to try to access the second page via the next button, i get the following error screen on my emulator.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds8w7.png)

Following the code i use:

```
class mobilitySurvey extends StatefulWidget {
  const mobilitySurvey({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<mobilitySurvey> createState() => _mobilitySurveyState();
}

class _mobilitySurveyState extends State<mobilitySurvey> {
  final _pageController = PageController();
  int _currentPage = 0;


  List<Widget> _pages = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pages = [      Page1(pageController: _pageController),      Page2(pageController: _pageController)];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        onPageChanged: (int page) {
          setState(() {
            _currentPage = page;
          });
        },
        children: _pages,
      ),
    );
  }
}



class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final PageController pageController;

  Page1({required this.pageController});

  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter your name';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter your email';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Next'),
            onPressed: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                // Save the form data and move to the next page
                _formKey.currentState!.save();
                widget.pageController.nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final PageController pageController;

  Page2({required this.pageController});

  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page1> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter your name';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter your email';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Next'),
            onPressed: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                // Save the form data and move to the next page
                _formKey.currentState!.save();
                widget.pageController.nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
              }
            },
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Back'),
            onPressed: () {
              widget.pageController.previousPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I think it does not change the state correctly. has anyone an idea?

Thanks

Moving to the second page when pressing next on the first page.

I expected to get to the second page but got the following error screen:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w72ZW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake,

I did not update `Page1` to `Page2` in the following:

```
class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final PageController pageController;

  Page2({required this.pageController});

  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page1> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

Comment: Just to be clear, your createState() method in Page2 is calling the Page1State and not the Page2State, so you're probably not showing page2?
And I don't think class names can include digits also